# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int - Error Message

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

***My Query***

```
Select * from MyTable
```

The table consists 300k rows.
It runs for 200k+ rows and this error pops up.

[image]

How to handle this to get the full data?

> Does MyTable have any computed columns?

***Table consists of a computed column with the name IsExceeds which is given below for your reference.***

[image]

***This is the computed column formula:***

```
(CONVERT([int],[Pro_PCT])-CONVERT([int],replace([Max_Off],'%','')))
```

***Field Definitions:***

```
[Pro_PCT] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Max_Off] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[IsExceeds]  AS (CONVERT([int],[Pro_PCT])-CONVERT([int],replace([Max_Off],'%','')))
```

Comment: Does MyTable have any computed columns? Probably best that you share the table definition

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags

Comment: Int data type just can store integer numbers , as it is obvious . you're trying to convert 11.11 to an int which is impossible .you should define the data type to float , double , ...

Comment: Unless there's a computed column (not persisted) in the table definition, I don't see how this query alone can produce this error.

Comment: Yes table consists a computed column.  I edited my post and included the field name and data type reference of that computed column for your reference.

Comment: We need to see the *calculation itself* and the definitions of any columns it references, not just an image showing that it is, indeed, Computed. Preferably a `CREATE TABLE` statement with all irrelevant columns removed, preferably as text rather than an image.

Comment: Updated the initial post with the required info.

Comment: Right, so you're storing some of your data in inappropriate data types and have `11.11` and possibly other values in one of the `Pro_Pct` and `Max_Off`. So `select top 100 * from MyTable where Pro_Pct like '%[^0-9]%' or Max_Off like '%[^0-9]%'` should give you a sample of the problematic rows. **Only you** know whether that'll mean correcting the data or adjusting the computed column.

Comment: You could convert it to numeric if that makes sense. Or convert to numeric, then int.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly convert in float then convert into int.

```
declare @n nvarchar(20)
set @n='11.11'

if (isnumeric(@n)=0)
 SELECT 0
   else 
      SELECT CAST(CONVERT(float, @n) as int) AS n
```

Comment: It is not a big deal, however it's better not to mix CAST and CONVERT. Stick to 1 of them and use it. Do either 2 CASTs or 2 CONVERTs. Is there any specific reason why did you use both of them together?

Comment: CONVERT(float, @n)   return  11.11 and CAST(CONVERT(float, @n) as int) return 11

Comment: why not CAST(CAST(@n AS FLOAT) AS INT) or CONVERT(int, CONVERT(float, @n))?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you storing amounts as strings?  That is the fundamental problem.

So, I would suggest fixing your data.  Something like this:

```
update mytable
    set max_off = replace(max_off, '%');

alter table mytable alter pro_pct numeric(10, 4);
alter table mytable alter max_off numeric(10, 4);
```

(Without sample data or an example of the data I am just guessing on a reasonable type.)

Then, you can define `IsExceeds` as:

```
(Pro_PCT - Max_Off)
```

Voila!  No problems.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the formula - either `Pro_PCT` or `Max_Off` contains the value `11.11` (well, with an extra `%` for `Max_Off`. Perhaps they also contain other values that can't be converted to `int`.

Here's what you can do to find all the rows that will cause this problem:

```
Select * 
from MyTable
where try_cast(Pro_PCT as int) is null
or try_cast(replace([Max_Off],'%','') as int) is null
```

After you've found them, you can either fix the values or change the calculation of the computed column to use `try_cast` or `try_convert` instead of `convert`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the bad data with

```
select  * from MyTable where isnumeric(  Max_Off ) = 0
```

Comment: Which would be *absolutely fine* telling you that `11.11` is numeric. Because `isnumeric` answers a question that no sane person has ever wanted to ask.

Comment: I agree but it still helps when trying to get a fast overview of bad data. Even better Select  distinct(Max_Off ) from MyTable where isnumeric(  Max_Off ) = 0. But I guess it realy depends on how wierd the data realy is

Comment: yes, but `isnumeric` doesn't guarantee the value can be converted to int. In fact, it doesn't even guarantee that it could be directly converted into *any* sql server numeric data type.