# SQL Server Pivot With Grand Total For Row And Column Sorting Issue In Left Side Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Using the below query to get the Grand Total for Row & Column in SQL server pivot which works as expected.

But the problem is the Question No is not sorting in asc to desc or desc to asc order.

Changing this

> ORDER BY sQtnNo asc

to ascending/descending don't have any effect.

```
/* COLUMNS HEADERS */
DECLARE @columnHeaders NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @columnHeaders  = COALESCE (@columnHeaders   
+ ',[' + sAnsText + ']', '[' + sAnsText + ']')


FROM   tblEntries  
GROUP BY sAnsText
ORDER BY sAnsText

/* GRAND TOTAL COLUMN */
DECLARE @GrandTotalCol  NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @GrandTotalCol = COALESCE (@GrandTotalCol + 'ISNULL ([' + 
CAST (sAnsText AS VARCHAR) +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + CAST(sAnsText AS VARCHAR)+ '],0) + ')
FROM     tblEntries 
  GROUP BY sAnsText
  ORDER BY sAnsText
  SET @GrandTotalCol = LEFT (@GrandTotalCol, LEN (@GrandTotalCol)-1)

/* GRAND TOTAL ROW */
DECLARE @GrandTotalRow  NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @GrandTotalRow = COALESCE(@GrandTotalRow + ',ISNULL(SUM([' + 
CAST(sAnsText AS VARCHAR)+']),0)', 'ISNULL(SUM([' + CAST(sAnsText AS VARCHAR)+']),0)')
FROM     tblEntries  
  GROUP BY sAnsText
  ORDER BY  sAnsText
----------------------------------------------

  -- DROP TABLE  temp_MatchesTotal

/* MAIN QUERY */
DECLARE @FinalQuery NVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @FinalQuery =   'SELECT *, (' + @GrandTotalCol + ') 
AS [Grand Total] INTO  #temp_MatchesTotal
       FROM
          (SELECT  sQtnNo as ''Sort'',sQtnNo ,sAnsText,1 as ''Qty''
             FROM  tblEntries 
          ) A
       PIVOT
          (
              sum (Qty)
              FOR sAnsText
              IN ('  +@columnHeaders +  ') 
          ) B 
          
ORDER BY sQtnNo asc

SELECT * FROM  #temp_MatchesTotal 


UNION ALL

SELECT ''Grand Total'','''','+@GrandTotalRow +',  
ISNULL (SUM([Grand Total]),0) FROM  #temp_MatchesTotal
  DROP TABLE  #temp_MatchesTotal'
  -- PRINT 'Pivot Query '+@FinalQuery
  -- SELECT @FinalQuery
  EXECUTE(@FinalQuery)
```

***Result is given below***

[image]

Any suggestion will be highly helpful.

Thanks in advance.

> When Using Try_Convert() Below Error Occurs

[image]

Comment: FYI, `'[' + ObjectName + ']'` is *not* safe from injection. Use `QUOTENAME`. You've also tagged 3 different versions of SQL Server here; none supported and 1 End of Life. What version are you *really* using?

Comment: Also, from that image, it looks like it's sorting correcty; clearly `Sort` is a string  data type (`varchar`?) and so that is exactly correct. `'14'` has a **lower** value than `'2'`. If you need your data to sort like a numerical value, then use a numerical data type.

Comment: Using SQL-Server-2014.  Currently the question No is defined as nvarchar(5) but if I change the Nvarchar to int then I am facing another issue in GrandTotal declaration which throws another type of error.

Comment: Side note: Some required reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Hosnestly, adding "totals" rows is something I personally see as something that should be done in the presentation layer, not the RDBMS. If, however, you want the column to sort like a numerical value, not a string value, then as I said, you need to make the column a numerical data type; either by making the column a numerical data type or using `(TRY_)CONVERT`.

Comment: *"Using SQL-Server-2014"* Then ***only*** tag that; don't add additional tags that aren't related to the question. Especially when one of those tags is for an End Of Life product. I have edited the tags for you, but please remember to tag correct in future. This isn't the first time you have been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157257/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-nvarchar-value-to-data-type-int-error-me#comment97053831_55157257), or even [second](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59575931/2).

Comment: it also fails when i use it in this way... right(''0''+sQtnNo,2) as ''Sort'' and ORDER BY sort asc

Comment: Look at [`(TRY_)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)[`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: both try/convert fails to convert the Nvarchar and creates other unnecessary problems and because of that the query throws error and exiting with error.

Comment: *"When Using Try_Convert() Below Error Occurs: {image of Conversion error}"* That is impossible; `TRY_CONVERT` explicitly **cannot** return a conversion error. If you are getting a conversion error, it's elsewhere you your code.

Answer (score 0):

Like Is aid in the comments, your column is a `varchar`, and strings don't order in the same order as a numerical value. `'14'` has a **lower** value than `'2'` and `'99'` has a **greater** value than `'843657365476547362'`.

If you want your columns to order like a numerical value, you need to treat them as a numerical value:

```
ORDER BY CASE Sort WHEN 'Grand Total' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC, --Put Grand Total at the bottom
         TRY_CONVERT(int,Sort) ASC;
```

Comment: With respect I doubt that, @Sixthsense . `14` is **greater** than `2`; it would be impossible for the same sort order

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f48076bdae33229313f276599342a59d) demonstrating working correctly, @Sixthsense .